# Starting Matlab with error "Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

Tags: gtk, matlab

When I start Matlab (R2021a) on Ubuntu Focal Fossa I receive the error

```
"Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

Re-Installing canberra-modules does not help.

Comment: That error shouldn't prevent it from running. Is it not running?

Answer (score 1):

When I add the export-path to the **.bashrc** the error is solved.

```
export GTK_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0
```

Comment: https://de.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/details/1995075 
says that this error-message is informational and 
has no effect on MATLAB.